# How to combine "xargs", "bash -c" and environment variables properly?

Tags: bash

Consider a directory as below:

```
user@ubuntu:~/tmp$ ls files
date03222020-pid001
date03222020-pid009
date03222020-pid011
date02222020-pid008
date01222020-pid031
date03122020-pid039
```

These files are created by a program and that program stored its last execution date in an environment variable named `LAST_EXECUTE`:

```
user@ubuntu:~/tmp$ echo $LAST_EXECUTE
date03222020
```

Now, I want to run a python script which accepts two parameters. The first parameter is file name and the second parameter is *pid* part of the file name. I want to run this python script on files which are created by the last execution. (i.e. files which are started by `$LAST_EXECUTE`).

I want to use `xargs`, `bash -c` and also [bash string substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) feature to do this and so I tried all the following substitutions (which all failed):

```
user@ubuntu:~/tmp$ ls files/$LAST_EXECUTE* | xargs -IX bash -c "python script.py X ${X#$LAST_EXECUTE}"

user@ubuntu:~/tmp$ ls files/$LAST_EXECUTE* | xargs -IX bash -c 'python script.py X ${X#$LAST_EXECUTE}'

user@ubuntu:~/tmp$ ls files/$LAST_EXECUTE* | xargs -IX bash -c "python script.py X \${X#$LAST_EXECUTE}"

user@ubuntu:~/tmp$ ls files/$LAST_EXECUTE* | xargs -IX bash -c "python script.py X \${X#\$LAST_EXECUTE}"

user@ubuntu:~/tmp$ ls files/$LAST_EXECUTE* | xargs -IX bash -c "python script.py X \$\{X#\$LAST_EXECUTE\}"
```

Expected output (for simplicity, let assume that the python script prints the parameters only):

```
date03222020-pid001     pid001
date03222020-pid009     pid009
date03222020-pid011     pid011
```

As you may notice, above files are files that have $LAST_EXECUTE in their name.

How can I do it?

(Note that: I don't want to modify the python script)

Comment: Why xargs but not a loop? For parallelism?

Comment: Yes, for parallelism.

Comment: What should the output be? Given the input you presented, with which parameters and how many python scripts should execute? What is the `${X#$LAST_EXCUTE}` supposed to do? You seem to want to run a single command or multiple?  `on files which are created by the last execution.` - which files would that be?

Comment: @KamilCuk I added the expected output to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the basis that it's better to understand how to diagnose and solve a problem than just be handed a solution, here's the process I went through to think through a solution:

To start with, I set up a test environment:

```
$ mkdir -p files
$ ( cd files; touch touch date03222020-pid001 date03222020-pid009 date03222020-pid011; )
$ export LAST_EXECUTE=date03222020
$ ls files/$LAST_EXECUTE*
files/date03222020-pid001  files/date03222020-pid009  files/date03222020-pid011
```

Now, let's just try to see what xargs is doing, by executing `echo` instead of the command:

```
$ ls files/$LAST_EXECUTE* | xargs -IX echo bash -c "python script.py X ${X#$LAST_EXECUTE}"
bash -c python script.py files/date03222020-pid001 
bash -c python script.py files/date03222020-pid009 
bash -c python script.py files/date03222020-pid011
```

Since `${X#LAST_EXECUTE}` is in double quotes, it's expanded as part of the `xargs` command. And since `$X` doesn't have a value it's logically turned into nothing.

We can give it a value to illustrate:

```
$ X=Hello
$ ls files/$LAST_EXECUTE* | xargs -IX echo bash -c "python script.py ${X#$LAST_EXECUTE}"
bash -c python script.py files/date03222020-pid001 Hello
bash -c python script.py files/date03222020-pid009 Hello
bash -c python script.py files/date03222020-pid011 Hello
```

But the intention of the `xargs` command is to substitute the string `X` with the argument, not to define the shell variable `$X`. And substituting the string `X` would also lead to undesired behaviour (particularly since there is an `X` in `LAST_EXECUTE`, as we can see by using single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
$ ls files/$LAST_EXECUTE* | xargs -IX echo bash -c 'python script.py X ${X#$LAST_EXECUTE}'
bash -c python script.py files/date03222020-pid001 ${files/date03222020-pid001#$LAST_Efiles/date03222020-pid001ECUTE}
bash -c python script.py files/date03222020-pid009 ${files/date03222020-pid009#$LAST_Efiles/date03222020-pid009ECUTE}
bash -c python script.py files/date03222020-pid011 ${files/date03222020-pid011#$LAST_Efiles/date03222020-pid011ECUTE}
```

If we were to try to actually execute that (by removing the `echo`), bash would interpret `${files/date03222020-pid011#$LAST_Efiles/date03222020-pid011ECUTE}` as a *string substitution* in the value of `$files`, not as a prefix deletion. But since there probably is no exported shell variable `$files`, that is also likely to result in an empty parameter expansion.

What we really want to do is actually much simpler: pass the argument from `xargs` to *bash*, not to the python script. Inside the bash script, we can manipulate the arguments as we choose. While we're at it, we'll try to properly quote the bash command line:

```
$ ls files/$LAST_EXECUTE* | xargs -IX echo bash -c 'python script.py "$1" "${1#$LAST_EXECUTE}"' _ X
bash -c python script.py "$1" "${1#$LAST_Efiles/date03222020-pid001ECUTE}" _ "files/date03222020-pid001"
bash -c python script.py "$1" "${1#$LAST_Efiles/date03222020-pid009ECUTE}" _ "files/date03222020-pid009"
bash -c python script.py "$1" "${1#$LAST_Efiles/date03222020-pid011ECUTE}" _ "files/date03222020-pid011"
```

Note the `_` in the above. `bash -c command` can be followed by more positional arguments. The first argument after the command is taken as the value of `$0` (the name of the shell interpreter), and the subsequent ones are `$1`, `$2`, …. This is slightly different from running a bash script; when we use `bash script.sh`, the next argument is `$1`, and `$0` is implicit. For this reason, it's generally considered bad style to use `$0` as a parameter (and it can lead to trouble because bash modifies its behaviour based on the name you give it). I could have used `bash` as the `$0` argument, which might be considered more correct, but `_` is shorter and more conventional. Anyway, it's the `_` which allows the next argument (`X`, which will be substituted with each argument read from xargs' input) to be passed through to the script as `$1`.

Also note I made no attempt to quote `X`. That's because `xargs` passes arguments through to the executed program verbatim (after substitution). It does not concatenate the arguments into a command line and invoke a shell to interpret the arguments. The difference is important, and you might want to experiment with it if that seemed confusing.

Anyway, that last change still doesn't cut it because, as mentioned above, `LAST_EXECUTE` has an `X` in it. You need to watch out for that, since xargs won't help. Single characters like `X` are really not good xargs substitution patterns, because they are far too likely to show up in your command strings without you even noticing. Instead, we'll use the commonly-used pattern: `{}`. That tends not to show up in command lines, but you still need to make sure that every use of {} is intended to be substituted:

```
$ ls files/$LAST_EXECUTE* | xargs -I{} echo bash -c 'python script.py "$1" "${1#$LAST_EXECUTE}"' _ {}
bash -c python script.py "$1" "${1#$LAST_EXECUTE}" _ files/date03222020-pid001
bash -c python script.py "$1" "${1#$LAST_EXECUTE}" _ files/date03222020-pid009
bash -c python script.py "$1" "${1#$LAST_EXECUTE}" _ files/date03222020-pid011
```

Now let's move the `echo` so that we actually invoke bash:

```
$ ls files/$LAST_EXECUTE* | xargs -I{} bash -c 'echo python script.py "$1" "${1#$LAST_EXECUTE}"' _ {}
python script.py files/date03222020-pid001 files/date03222020-pid001
python script.py files/date03222020-pid009 files/date03222020-pid009
python script.py files/date03222020-pid011 files/date03222020-pid011
```

OK, we're getting closer. But that makes it quite obvious that prefix-deleting `$LAST_EXECUTE` won't work, because it's not the prefix. It should have been `files/$LAST_EXECUTE`:

```
$ ls files/$LAST_EXECUTE* | xargs -I{} bash -c 'echo python script.py "$1" "${1#files/$LAST_EXECUTE}"' _ {}
python script.py files/date03222020-pid001 -pid001
python script.py files/date03222020-pid009 -pid009
python script.py files/date03222020-pid011 -pid011
```

Or better `files/$LAST_EXECUTE-`

```
$ ls files/$LAST_EXECUTE* | xargs -I{} bash -c 'echo python script.py "$1" "${1#files/$LAST_EXECUTE-}"' _ {}
python script.py files/date03222020-pid001 pid001
python script.py files/date03222020-pid009 pid009
python script.py files/date03222020-pid011 pid011
```

Finally, we really should avoid trying to parse `ls`. Although these filenames are probably well-behaved, there is really no way to know for sure what a filename might look like. It might include whitespace, even newline characters, so there's no guarantee that xargs will divide the input up correctly.

Anyway, there's no good reason for that `ls`. The arguments to `ls` come from the expansion of a glob, so the only value `ls` is adding is to put the filenames on individual lines. We could just use the glob expansion directly, which is much better because the shell doesn't make any attempt to word-split or otherwise process the result of a glob expansion. In order to give xargs a well-delimited sequence of input arguments, we can use `printf` to put NULs between arguments instead of newlines, since no filename can contain a NUL character, and then tell xargs to divide the input at NUL characters using the (non-standard but commonly-implemented) `-0` option:

```
$ printf '%s\0' files/$LAST_EXECUTE* | xargs -0 -I{} bash -c 'echo python script.py "$1" "${1#files/$LAST_EXECUTE-}"' _ {}
python script.py files/date03222020-pid001 pid001
python script.py files/date03222020-pid009 pid009
python script.py files/date03222020-pid011 pid011
```

Comment: Aewsome! What does that `_ X ` or `_ {}` mean at the end of commands in the last 5 snippets?

Comment: Added the answer to your question to the answer, rather than leaving it here in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

[Do not parse ls output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

Preparse filenames with some regex and just run the python script:

```
find files -name "${LAST_EXECUTE}-pid*" | 
sed 's/-\(pid[0-9]*\)$/&\n\1/' |
xargs -d$'\n' -n2 python script.py
```

If you really have to run bash, I advise to use single quotes and pass context using exported environment variables or arguments. Remember that first argument after script is `$0`.

```
find files -name "$LAST_EXECUTE*" |
xargs -d$'\n' -n1 bash -c '
    LAST_EXECUTE=$1
    arg=$(basename "$2")       
    python script.py "$2" "${arg#${LAST_EXECUTE}-}"
' -- "$LAST_EXECUTE"
```

[Tested on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/SecondaryFirsthandFormats).

Comment: Thank you for  your great answer. May I ask you to add some explanations on the second solution. (for example, what are those dashes on the last line?)

Comment: `first argument after script is $0`. `bash -c 'echo \$0=$0' this_is_zero_argument this_is_first_argument this_is_second_argument`. For reference [bash invoking bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash-1) under `-c` option. You could use `$0` in the script, but I feel like using positional parameters from `$1` is more natural, readable, understandable and easier then to move to a normal script. Poeple usually use `--` or `_` or `-` for `$0` placeholder.

Comment: And what if I want to use xargs for parallelism with separate output files (redirect python output to a file)? Is it possible using the first solution? I mean as I need to separate output files, I need to use "bash -c". Can you please modify the first solution to run the python script multi-thread with separate output file.

Comment: No, you have to script that yourself.

Comment: Hi @Abraham, I'll add an answer shortly (based on Kamil's work) that wites the output to different files in paralle.

Comment: I don't think the point of "don't parse ls" is to just use `find` instead. Use `find`'s `-print0` option, or use a glob. Using `find` to produce an unreliably terminated list of filenames has no advantage over using `ls` to do that, if `ls` would work (flat directory).

Answer (score 1):

To run xargs in parallel with the results output to different files:

```
find files -name "$LAST_EXECUTE*" |
xargs  -P${PROCESSES:=30} -d$'\n' -n1 bash -c '
    LAST_EXECUTE=$1
    arg=$(basename "$2")       
    python script.py "$2" "${arg#${LAST_EXECUTE}-}" > $2.out
' -- "$LAST_EXECUTE"
```

Above, you can specify the number of parallel processes by setting the `PROCESSES` environment variable or accept the default of 30.   Aside from running the commands in parallel with `-P`, you can capture each file named from the argument passed in by xargs (`$2` in the code above).  As you can see, I append the suffix `.out` to each output file based on the input filename.